# React app shows props.location.state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble accessing props.location.state inside the useEffect() hook. This is how it looks like:

```
useEffect((props) => {
    console.log("location: :", props.location.state); 
}, [props])
```

It is showing that props.location.state is undefined. Why would it be undefined and how can I set it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show some more of your code? What is the `location` you are passing as props to this component?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the `props` from callback, not that `props` what you want to use. You have to remove argument `props` from callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("location: :", props.location.state); 
}, [props])
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `useEffect` is an array of values, the if any one of them changes, the effect should run. As a best practice, you should only put in values here that you need for the effect. I would change it to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("location: :", props.location.state); 
}, [props.location.state]);
```

You could also not use that second argument at all:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("location: :", props.location.state); 
});
```

Take a look at the React `onEffect` docs for more information:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html